# If statement from different sheet base on two cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a 2 sheets,Summary & Remarks and I'm trying to create a REMARKS ERROR base on summary sheet data.

Example.
In Sheet Summary if both area01 & area02 has no equivalent area code in column 
E8 & E9 the REMARKS ERROR! will appear in Sheet REMARKS.

And When one of the two areas
(E8 or E9) has data, the error will not appear in REMARKS SHEET

Can someone help me, please? Please see attached Google sheet

[REMARKS_SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PpbiP1EhhzmnSL2l1VzEAkM82S4xQmVkOC9s-u0U2uM/copy)

Comment: sheet is private!

Comment: Sir please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF(TRIM(C9)=LEFT(D8, 4), IFNA(VLOOKUP(F8, I:J, 2, 0), ))
```

or arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRIM(C9)=LEFT(D8:D, 4), IFNA(VLOOKUP(F8:F, I:J, 2, 0), ), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=IF((SUMMARY!C9="AREA")*
   ((SUMMARY!D8<>"")+(SUMMARY!D9<>""))*
   ((SUMMARY!E8 ="")+(SUMMARY!E9 ="")), 
 "ERROR: NO AREA CODE UPDATED", )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sir in the array formula, can i change the range to 

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRIM(C9)=LEFT(D8:D9, 4), IFNA(VLOOKUP(F8:F9, I:J, 2, 0), ), ))

Comment: The result is still the same sir

Comment: what should be the expected result? can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CyrqBKWrTtsFU15wNICWBRB3ozID_2ejszvobV5tDx0/edit#gid=1114869593